# application is not loading in ipad retina 64 bit simulator/ ipad air simulator

Tags: ipad, ios7, xcode5, ios8

I have created application using xcode 5.1.1. I'm able to run the application in ipad and ipad retina simulators. Its is not working in ipad retina (64 bit) simulator and ipad Air simulator. I tried with iPad air device also. I checked the system architecture and its set t0 arv7 armv7s arm64.
Could you please tell me whats going wrong. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

This is the code i'm using to draw it. It works well in non 64 bit devices and simulators.

```
CAShapeLayer *layer=[CAShapeLayer layer]; 
styledPath.path.lineWidth = self.countryBorderWidth; 
layer.path=styledPath.path.CGPath;
layer.fillColor=self.defaultCountryFillColor.CGColor; 
layer.strokeColor=self.defaultCountryBorderColor.CGColor; 
[self.svgContainerView.layer addSublayer:layer]; 
[self.shapeLayerArray addObject:layer]; 
[self.styledPathArray addObject:styledPath];
```

Comment: Application is loading in simulator with empty screen. I'm not able to see my objects in application. no error i'm getting.

Comment: So it is loading it's just not loading your rootViewController ?

Comment: yes. my controller is loading not my objects. I'm drawing some shapes using caShapelayers. That is not coming up in screen.

Comment: Maybe share some code? Kind of impossible to help you based on your question.

Comment: This is the code i'm using to draw it. It works well in non 64 bit devices and simulators.                                                               CAShapeLayer *layer=[CAShapeLayer layer];
        styledPath.path.lineWidth = self.countryBorderWidth;
        layer.path=styledPath.path.CGPath;
        layer.fillColor=self.defaultCountryFillColor.CGColor;
        layer.strokeColor=self.defaultCountryBorderColor.CGColor;
        [self.svgContainerView.layer addSublayer:layer];
        [self.shapeLayerArray addObject:layer];
        [self.styledPathArray addObject:styledPath];

Comment: I don't see code to add the new layer to the view.

Comment: This is where i'm adding layer to view.[self.svgContainerView.layer addSublayer:layer];